# How do I insert a row with an identity column with DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

I'm trying to use DataGrip, I have come across a major blocker.

I have a Sql Azure table with a primary key "Id" field that is set as an `Identity(1,1)`.  In DataGrip, it shows the column as `Id INT (auto increment)`.

I clicked on the table and opened the table editor.  I then added a new record but left the `Id` column blank.  However, when I go to commit my changes, it says that it cannot insert explicit values for identity column.

Is it not possible to add new records in DataGrip with an identity column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2922) was fixed a couple years ago.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a record with an identity column, you would need to turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` for the particular table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188059.aspx

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblYourTable ON
INSERT INTO tblYourTable (ID, Name...) VALUES (1, 'Foo', ...)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblYourTable OFF
```

It is worth noting that this is not something you should leave on, as the expectation is you want to only do this for a few records. For example, to import previous data.

Comment: Not only does this not utilize the Datagrip tooling at all, it's extremely error prone and can cause exceptions if I"m trying to insert data into a production database.  Furthermore, if I"m doing an insert statement manually I might as well Just leave the ID column out and not deal with identity_insert.